# Подскажите как перебрать option и получить Index

Tags: javascript, html, select

1. Ожидается получать index выбраного option
2. когда текущий option не выбран пользователем стоит, тоже нужно чтобы выводился index
   (по index я буду делать сравнения)

```js
  function calc(){ 
    const typeCar = document.querySelectorAll(".typeCar");
  function actionSbor(typeCar, stateAction) {
    typeCar.forEach((element, index, array) => {
      element.addEventListener("change", function () {
        console.log(index);
      });
    });
  }
   actionSbor(typeCar, stateAction);
  }
```

```html
 <select onchange="calc()" class="typeCar">
               <option value="">Легковый</option>
               <option value="">Кроссовер</option>
               <option value="">Пикап / Микроавтобус </option>
               <option value="400">Мотоцикл</option>
  </select><br/><br/>
```

Comment: _«перебрать select»_ - невозможно перебрать то что есть в единственном экземпляре. А для перебора опций селекта, можно использовать его свойство `options` (содержит NodeList дочерних option-элементов).  **1.** `const poluchat = typeCar.selectedIndex;` **2.** уже есть в коде, это выражение `console.log(index);` - помести его в цикл по тому что желаешь перебирать.

Comment: ...хотя смысл вывода индексов невыбранных опций, для меня является загадкой, ведь с тем же успехом можно просто вывести числа от 0 до `selectElem.options.length` и не мучить DOM на каждой итерации. Наверное, я просто суть задачи №2 не улавливаю по тому что написано.

Comment: спасибо, суть задачи 2 состоит в том, что если юзер увидит что option стоит уже нужный, он может даже не кликнуть, по select, таким образом я не получу index, который мне понадобится для сравнения с другими данными...

Answer (score 1):

```js
addEventListener(`change`, e => {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains(`typeCar`)) return;
  alert(`${e.target.value}\r\n${e.target.querySelector(`[value='${e.target.value}']`).textContent}`);
});

document.querySelector(`.typeCar`).dispatchEvent(new Event(`change`, {
  bubbles: true
}));
```

```html
<select onchange="calc()" class="typeCar">
  <option value="1">Легковый</option>
  <option value="2">Кроссовер</option>
  <option value="3">Пикап / Микроавтобус </option>
  <option value="4">Мотоцикл</option>
</select>
```